# sum values in dictionary less than a certain value

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, aggregate

I have the following dictionary and am trying to make a pie chart from them but I want to only include the top 5 (they are already sorted by value here) and then sum the others together in an `Other` category i.e. replace `Publishing`, `Fashion`, `Food` etc. with just one `Other` which sum them all together. Stuck with how to do this so would appreciate any help!

```
{'Games': 715067930.8599964,
 'Design': 705237125.089998,
 'Technology': 648570433.7599969,
 'Film & Video': 379559714.56000066,
 'Music': 191227757.8699999,
 'Publishing': 130763828.65999977,
 'Fashion': 125678824.47999984,
 'Food': 122781563.58000016,
 'Art': 89078801.8599998,
 'Comics': 70600202.99999984,
 'Theater': 42662109.69999992,
 'Photography': 37709926.38000007,
 'Crafts': 13953818.35000002,
 'Dance': 12908120.519999994,
 'Journalism': 12197353.370000007}
```

At the moment my pie chart is really overcrowded using this code

```
groupbycategorypledge = df.groupby('main_category')['usd_pledged_real'].sum().sort_values(ascending=False)
plt.figure(figsize=(20, 10))
pie = groupbycategorypledge.plot(kind='pie', startangle=90, radius=0.7, title='Amount Pledged by Main category',autopct='%1.1f%%',labeldistance=1.2)
plt.legend(loc=(1.05,0.75))
plt.ylabel('')
```

so I have

```
dict = groupbycategorypledge.sort_values(ascending=False).to_dict()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manipulate your dictionary *before* using Pandas:

```
from operator import itemgetter

# sort by value descending
items_sorted = sorted(d.items(), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)

# calculate sum of others
others = ('Other', sum(map(itemgetter(1), items_sorted[5:])))

# construct dictionary
d = dict([*items_sorted[:5], others])

print(d)

{'Games': 715067930.8599964,
 'Design': 705237125.089998,
 'Technology': 648570433.7599969,
 'Film & Video': 379559714.56000066,
 'Music': 191227757.8699999,
 'Other': 658334549.8999995}
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on the idea of @jpp, but using a [heap](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html):

```
import heapq

d = {'Games': 715067930.8599964,
     'Design': 705237125.089998,
     'Technology': 648570433.7599969,
     'Film & Video': 379559714.56000066,
     'Music': 191227757.8699999,
     'Publishing': 130763828.65999977,
     'Fashion': 125678824.47999984,
     'Food': 122781563.58000016,
     'Art': 89078801.8599998,
     'Comics': 70600202.99999984,
     'Theater': 42662109.69999992,
     'Photography': 37709926.38000007,
     'Crafts': 13953818.35000002,
     'Dance': 12908120.519999994,
     'Journalism': 12197353.370000007}

top_5 = set(heapq.nlargest(5, d, key=d.get))

groups = {}
for category, pledge in d.items():
    new_category = category if category in top_5 else 'Other'
    groups.setdefault(new_category, []).append(pledge)

result = {k: sum(v) for k, v in groups.items()}
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
{'Technology': 648570433.7599969, 'Design': 705237125.089998, 'Other': 658334549.8999994, 'Games': 715067930.8599964, 'Film & Video': 379559714.56000066, 'Music': 191227757.8699999}
```

Or if you fancy numpy:

```
import numpy as np

d = {'Games': 715067930.8599964,
     'Design': 705237125.089998,
     'Technology': 648570433.7599969,
     'Film & Video': 379559714.56000066,
     'Music': 191227757.8699999,
     'Publishing': 130763828.65999977,
     'Fashion': 125678824.47999984,
     'Food': 122781563.58000016,
     'Art': 89078801.8599998,
     'Comics': 70600202.99999984,
     'Theater': 42662109.69999992,
     'Photography': 37709926.38000007,
     'Crafts': 13953818.35000002,
     'Dance': 12908120.519999994,
     'Journalism': 12197353.370000007}

categories, pledge_values = map(np.array, zip(*d.items()))
partition = np.argpartition(pledge_values, -5)
top_5 = set(categories[partition][-5:])

groups = {}
for category, pledge in d.items():
    new_category = category if category in top_5 else 'Other'
    groups.setdefault(new_category, []).append(pledge)

result = {k: sum(v) for k, v in groups.items()}
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
{'Technology': 648570433.7599969, 'Design': 705237125.089998, 'Other': 658334549.8999995, 'Music': 191227757.8699999, 'Games': 715067930.8599964, 'Film & Video': 379559714.56000066}
```

The complexity of the second proposal (using numpy) is *O(n)* where `n` is the number of key, value pairs of `d`.